# Python nonsense syntax error, indented blocks

Tags: python

In this code:

```
    k = (input("Pizza vegetariana? (s/n):\n"))
print("Ingredientes:")
if k == 's':
        print("1. Pimiento\n2. Tofu")
        print("Elija el número de la opción")
elif k == 'n':
        print("1. Peperoni\n2. Jamón\n3. Salmón\n")
        for x in range(3):
            l = int(input("Elija un número de las opciones:\n")
            if l == 1:
                 n ="Peperoni "
            elif l == 2:
                 n ="Jamón "
            elif l == 3:
                 n ="Salmón "
        print("Ingredientes elegidos: \n"
+n+"\nMozzarella"+"\nTomate")
else:
        print("Tiene que introducir una \"s\" ó \"n\"")
```

Why does it give me a syntax error?

*File "", line 10
if l == 1:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

Comment: because the line above is missing a bracket `)`

Answer (score 1):

Because in the previous line you forgot to close the brackets for the int()

```
l = int(input("Elija un número de las opciones:\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an ")" missing in line 9

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket on line 9. Also, consistent indentation is very important in python. Make sure you maintain it throughout your code. The corrected code is as follows:

```
k = (input("Pizza vegetariana? (s/n):\n"))
print("Ingredientes:")
if k == 's':
    print("1. Pimiento\n2. Tofu")
    print("Elija el número de la opción")
elif k == 'n':
    print("1. Peperoni\n2. Jamón\n3. Salmón\n")
    for x in range(3):
        l = int(input("Elija un número de las opciones:\n"))
        if l == 1:
            n ="Peperoni "
        elif l == 2:
            n ="Jamón "
        elif l == 3:
            n ="Salmón "
    print("Ingredientes elegidos: \n"+n+"\nMozzarella"+"\nTomate")
else:
    print("Tiene que introducir una \"s\" ó \"n\"")
```